# Generate All Possible combinations of a Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

How can I generate ALL possible values for an N*M matrix, knowing that elements of this matrix can only be either be 0 or 1?

For example if I want a 2*2 matrix, we get 16 matrices with the different possible combinations: [0 0;0 0], [1 1;1 1], [1 0;0 1],[1 1; 0 0],[0 0;1 1]...etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **[`dec2base`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/dec2base.html)** -

```
combs = dec2base(0:power(2,N*M)-1,2) - '0'
```

This generates all the possible combinations in rows. So, to select any combination, you need to index into `combs`. Thus, the first combination `[0,0,0,0]` would be available at `combs(1,:)` and the last one `[1,1,1,1]` would be at `comb(end,:)`.

If your possible values are from a different set, like `0,1,2,3` instead, make this edit -

```
combs = dec2base(0:power(4,N*M)-1,4) - '0'
```

---

If you would to get the combinations that would be sized identically to the input matrix, use this -

```
combs_matshaped = reshape(permute(combs,[3 2 1]),N,M,[])
```

This creates a 3D array of as many 2D slices as there are combinations and each combination for the matrix is "index-able" with the third dimension index. For example, if you intend to get the first combination, use `combs_matshaped(:,:,1)` and for the last one, use `combs_matshaped(:,:,end)`.

Comment: perfect, great answer! Oh maybe just add `reshape(combs(1,:), N, M)` for completeness

Comment: @Divakar combs(1,:) will extract  it as a vector not a matrix, is there a way to do so without using a loop?

Comment: thats fine, Dan answered me

Comment: @AmiraAkra Check out the edits on how to get those matrices without loops and everything in one go!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (although [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25641077/2586922) is simpler and probably faster):

```
c = cell(1,N*M);
[c{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid([0 1 2 3 ]); %// or change set of values: [0 1 2 3] etc
combs = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(:), c, 'uni', 0)); %// results as row vectors
combs = reshape(combs.',N,M,[]); %// NxM matrices: combs(:,:,1), combs(:,:,2),...
```