# Changing the size of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am given the following matrices `A` of size 3x1 and `B` of size 5x1

```
A =   B=

1     A
2     B
3     C
      D 
      E
```

I want to convert matrix `C` in a 15x2 matrix

```
C =  

1   A  
1   B  
1   C  
1   D
1   E
2   A
  .
  .
  .
3   E
```

How can I make it?

Comment: look into `repmat`, `kron`, etc...  I bet a dollar Luis will answer with a bsxfun in the next 15 minutes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different alternative based on code for generating truth tables from [Generate All Possible combinations of a Matrix in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641029/generate-all-possible-combinations-of-a-matrix-in-matlab)

```
ind = dec2base(0:power(5,2)-1,5)-47;
C = [A(ind(1:15,1) + 48, B(ind(1:15,2)];
```

And if you want to generalize it

```
m = max(size(A,1),size(B,1));
n = size(A,1)*size(B,1);
col = 2;
ind = dec2base(0:power(n,col)-1,n)-47;
ind = ind(1:n,:);
C = [A(ind(:,1) + 48, B(ind(:,2)];
```

The `+ 48` is just to convert your `A` matrix from a numerical matrix to a char matrix so that `C` can hold both number and letters. You can leave it out if `A` was already a char matrix.

What's useful about this technique is that by changing `col`, this generalizes to combing more than just 2 vectors in a similar fashion

Answer (score 3):

Can be done with `repmat`

```
D = repmat(A',size(B,1),1);
C = [D(:),repmat(B,size(A,1),1)]
```

Comment: I think you have to convert `D` to a char array first don't you? `C = [D(:)+48,repmat(B,size(A,1),1)]` seems to do it

Comment: I assumed, the chars were only for illustration. Otherwise, he should probably use cells.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that since 2015a you can replace `D` with `repelem` like `C = [repelem(A,size(B,1)), repmat(B, size(A,1),1)]`