# How to get all the possible combinations of elements in a matrix, but don't allow exchange of elements inbetween columns?

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations, permutation

Lets say I have this matrice A: [3 x 4]

```
      1     4     7    10
      2     5     8    11
      3     6     9    12
```

I want to permute the element of in each column, but they can't change to a different column, so `1 2 3` need to always be part of the first column. So for exemple I want:

```
      3     4     8    10
      1     5     7    11
      2     6     9    12
      3     4     8    11
      1     6     7    10
      2     5     9    12
      1     6     9    11
      .     .     .     .
```

So in one matrix I would like to have all the possible permutation, in this case, there are 3 different choices `3x3x3x3=81`possibilities.So my result matrixe should be `81x4`, because I only need each time one `[1x4]`line vector answer, and that 81 time.

An other way to as the question would be (for the same end for me), would be, if I have 4 column vector:

```
     a=[1;2;3]
     b=[4;5;6]
     c=[7;8;9]
     d=[10;11;12;13]
```

Compare to my previous exemple, each column vector can have a different number of row. Then is like I have 4 boxes, A, B C, D and I can only put one element of a in A, b in B and so on; so I would like to get all the permutation possible with the answer `[A B C D]` beeing a `[1x4]` row, and in this case, I would have `3x3x3x4=108` different row. So where I have been missunderstood (my fault), is that I don't want all the different [3x4] matrix answers but just [1x4]lines.

so in this case the answer would be:

```
     1 4 7 10
and  1 4 7 11
and  1 4 7 12
and  1 4 7 13
and  2 4 8 10
and  ...
until there are the 108 combinations
```

The fonction `perms` in Matlab can't do that since I don't want to permute all the matrix (and btw, this is already a too big matrix to do so).

So do you have any idea how I could do this or is there is a fonction which can do that? I, off course, also could have matrix which have different size. Thank you

Comment: Aren't there `3! == 6` permutations per column?

Comment: Each column should have `3!=6` possible permutations, so there are `6^4=1296` possible matrices

Comment: No because in my case, the number need to stay in each column, so I can't have the numer  `2 ` for exemple in the column 4. So to have each permutation, without any doubles, it give  `3^4=81 ` Possibilities, for what I want. Maybe I didn't explain it well, I am not trying to get a [3x4] matrix as an aswer, but for my purpose, I need each time a [1x4] vector answered. and that 81 times. Actually those numbers will be the column number of an other matrix that I use to estimate some index and optimized them. I hope it help to understand better my question.

Comment: @MarieM. you get 1296 leaving the number in the columns. You'd get 81 if you just wanted each possible row but what you're asking for is each possible group of 3 rows which is why it's 6^4 instead of 3^4.

Comment: I guess I miss explain myself, I want each possible row, and not 3 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to get all combinations of 4x the permutations of `1:3`.
You could generate these with `combvec` from the Neural Networks Toolbox ([like @brainkz did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38593302/1162609)), or with [permn from the File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-permn-v--n--k-/content/permn.m).

After that it's a matter of managing indices, applying [sub2ind](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) (with the correct column index) and rearranging until everything is in the order you want.

```
a = [1     4     7    10
     2     5     8    11
     3     6     9    12];

siz = size(a);
perm1 = perms(1:siz(1));
Nperm1 = size(perm1,1); % = factorial(siz(1))
perm2 = permn(1:Nperm1, siz(2) );
Nperm2 = size(perm2,1);
permidx = reshape(perm1(perm2,:)', [Nperm2 siz(1), siz(2)]); % reshape unnecessary, easier for debugging

col_base_idx = 1:siz(2);
col_idx = col_base_idx(ones(Nperm2*siz(1) ,1),:);
lin_idx = reshape(sub2ind(size(a), permidx(:), col_idx(:)), [Nperm2*siz(1) siz(2)]);

result = a(lin_idx);
```

This avoids any loops or cell concatenation and uses straigh indexing instead.

### Permutations per column, unique rows

Same method:

```
siz = size(a);
permidx = permn(1:siz(1), siz(2) );
Npermidx = size(permidx, 1);
col_base_idx = 1:siz(2);
col_idx = col_base_idx(ones(Npermidx, 1),:);
lin_idx = reshape(sub2ind(size(a), permidx(:), col_idx(:)), [Npermidx siz(2)]);

result = a(lin_idx);
```

Comment: It's almost that, but actually, as I edit my answer, I don't need a [3x4] answer but only a [1x4] answer, and so to have all the permutation, I should get 81 answer. I will check all the answers tomorrow and see what I can do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you, the second part is what I need, do you think with that kind of method I can change it so that instead of having a `a [3x4]` matrix, I would have 4 different column vectors wich may have different size, so `[3x1], [3x1], [3x1] and [4x1]` for exemple? (As in the second part of my question that I edited)

Comment: no, this method assumes fixed number of rows, it just permutes `1:NumRows`

Answer (score 1):

Your question appeared to be a very interesting brain-teaser. I suggest the following:

```
in = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;10,11,12]';
b = perms(1:3);
a = 1:size(b,1);
c = combvec(a,a,a,a);
for k = 1:length(c(1,:))
    out{k} = [in(b(c(1,k),:),1),in(b(c(2,k),:),2),in(b(c(3,k),:),3),in(b(c(4,k),:),4)];
end
%and if you want your result as an ordinary array:
out = vertcat(out{:});
```

`b` is a `6x3` array that contains all possible permutations of `[1,2,3]`. `c` is `4x1296` array that contains all possible combinations of elements in `a = 1:6`. In the for loop we use number from 1 to 6 to get the permutation in `b`, and that permutation is used as indices to the column.

Hope that helps

Comment: nice one on the combvec

Answer (score 1):

this is another octave friendly solution:

```
function result = Tuples(A)
    [P,n]= size(A);
    M = reshape(repmat(1:P,  1, P ^(n-1)), repmat(P, 1, n));
    result = zeros(P^ n, n);
    for i = 1:n
        result(:, i) = A(reshape(permute(M, circshift((1:n)', i)), P ^ n, 1), i);
    end
end
%%%example
A = [...
      1     4     7    10;...
      2     5     8    11;...
      3     6     9    12];
result = Tuples(A)
```

Update:
Question updated that: given  n vectors of different length generates a list of all possible tuples whose ith element is from vector i:

```
function result = Tuples( A)
    if exist('repelem') ==0
        repelem = @(v,n) repelems(v,[1:numel(v);n]);
    end
    n = numel(A);
    siz = [ cell2mat(cellfun(@numel, A , 'UniformOutput', false))];
    tot_prd = prod(siz);
    cum_prd=cumprod(siz);
    tot_cum = tot_prd ./ cum_prd;
    cum_siz = cum_prd ./ siz;
    result = zeros(tot_prd, n);
    for i = 1: n
        result(:, i) = repmat(repelem(A{i},repmat(tot_cum(i),1,siz(i))) ,1,cum_siz(i));
    end
end
%%%%example
a = {...
        [1;2;3],...
        [4;5;6],...
        [7;8;9],...
        [10;11;12;13]...
    };
result =Tuples(a)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's totally answering the first part of my question, I haved edit it a little bit. How should I do that, if instead of having  a matrix A, I would have 4 column vector, and I want to permute them the same way as the matrix, but the vectors can have different size? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated but it works without the need for any additional toolboxes:

You basically want a `b` element 'truth table' which you can generate like this ([adapted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641029/generate-all-possible-combinations-of-a-matrix-in-matlab)) if you were applying it to each element:

```
[b, n] = size(A)
truthtable = dec2base(0:power(b,n)-1, b) - '0'
```

Now you need to convert the truth table to linear indexes by adding the column number times the total number of rows:

```
idx = bsxfun(@plus, b*(0:n-1)+1, truthtable)
```

now you instead of applying this truth table to each element you actually want to apply it to each permutation. There are `6` permutations so `b` becomes `6`. The trick is to then create a `6`-by-`1` cell array where each element has a distinct permutation of `[1,2,3]` and then apply the truth table idea to that:

```
[m,n] = size(A);
b = factorial(m);
permutations = reshape(perms(1:m)',[],1);
permCell = mat2cell(permutations,ones(b,1)*m,1);

truthtable = dec2base(0:power(b,n)-1, b) - '0';
expandedTT = cell2mat(permCell(truthtable + 1));
idx = bsxfun(@plus, m*(0:n-1), expandedTT);

A(idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer. Rather specific just to demonstrate the concept, but can easily be adapted.

```
A = [1,4,7,10;2,5,8,11;3,6,9,12];
P = perms(1:3)'
[X,Y,Z,W] = ndgrid(1:6,1:6,1:6,1:6);
```

You now have 1296 permutations. If you wanted to access, say, the 400th one:

```
Permutation_within_column = [P(:,X(400)), P(:,Y(400)), P(:,Z(400)), P(:,W(400))];
ColumnOffset = repmat([0:3]*3,[3,1])
My_permutation = Permutation_within_column + ColumnOffset; % results in valid linear indices
A(My_permutation)
```

This approach allows you to obtain the 400th permutation on demand; if you prefer to have all possible permutations concatenated in the 3rd dimension, (i.e. a 3x4x1296 matrix), you can either do this with a `for` loop, or simply adapt the above and vectorise; for example, if you wanted to create a 3x4x2 matrix holding the first two permutations along the 3rd dimension:

```
Permutations_within_columns = reshape(P(:,X(1:2)),3,1,[]);
Permutations_within_columns = cat(2, Permutations_within_columns, reshape(P(:,Y(1:2)),3,1,[]));
Permutations_within_columns = cat(2, Permutations_within_columns, reshape(P(:,Z(1:2)),3,1,[]));
Permutations_within_columns = cat(2, Permutations_within_columns, reshape(P(:,W(1:2)),3,1,[]));
ColumnOffsets = repmat([0:3]*3,[3,1,2]);
My_permutations = Permutations_within_columns + ColumnOffsets;
A(My_permutations)
```

This approach enables you to collect a specific subrange, **which may be useful if available memory is a concern** (i.e. for larger matrices) and you'd prefer to perform your operations by blocks. If memory isn't a concern you can get all 1296 permutations at once in one giant matrix if you wish; just adapt as appropriate (e.g. replicate ColumnOffsets the right number of times in the 3rd dimension)

Comment: To clarify, when I say "specific" I mean I used magic numbers rather than generic `size` instructions etc because I'm sure you can adapt those appropriately. (i.e. by 'specific' I did not mean that the method won't work in general)

Comment: Btw, this method has the obvious benefit of being able to generate the permutation easily on demand, rather than having to store all possible ones in a giant memory-eating matrix instead. If you simply want to perform comparisons or calculate statistics between any two permutations at any given time, rather than a single statistic over the *entire* 3x4x1296 matrix of all possible permutations, then this is the way to go.